# Getting transaction receipt with a reverted transaction to determine how much gas was used?

Tags: web3js, revert-opcode

In web3.js, if a revert occurs, it doesn't give a receipt along with it. I want to determine how much gas was actually used after a revert.

In 1.0, I can't even get the tx hash from the event transmitter.

Comment: I have a custom `geth` which gives you the real gas estimation on any transaction, erroneous or not, with gas refunds or without, contact me and I will send you the code

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT**: The below only works for ganache.

---

In my testing, the below works. The function `storeAndRevert`, as you might imagine, stores the argument in a state variable and then `revert`s:

```
instance.methods.storeAndRevert(42).send({ from: accounts[0], gas: 3000000 })
.on('error', async (err) => {
  const receipt = await web3.eth.getTransactionReceipt(err.hashes[0]);
  console.log(`Gas used: ${receipt.gasUsed}`);
});
```

As far as I know, the `error` event is the only one you'll be able to listen for, though I think `try/catch` will give you access to the same error object.

Comment: This doesn't work for me. I'm using web3 1.0.0-beta.36. I tested your exact code on a function which reverts. The err parameter is a string for me, not an object.

Comment: Yes, this send to only work with ganache. I'll edit the answer.

Comment: I am using this on ganache actually...

I am assuming that instance is a web3.eth.Contract instance?

Comment: Yes. This may vary depending on the `ganache` version? I was using `ganache-core` at version 2.2.1.

Comment: I am testing this on the latest ganache-cli and ganache-core (2.2.1) versions.